# Maximization of function that does not depend on all variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to solve a maximization problem similar to

```
Maximize[{- E^x + E^y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y}]
```

Mathematica correctly solves this problem. However, I have additional variables that are irrelevant to the maximization problem:

```
Maximize[{- E^x + E^y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

Mathematica cannot solve this problem. What can I do to still solve this problem? What if z additionally occurs in the constraints, as in the following line?

```
Maximize[{- E^x + E^y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && x <= z}, {x, y, z}]
```

Interestingly, Mathematica *can* solve this:

```
Maximize[{-E^x + E^y + E^z, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

---

**Expected behavior**: Because $z$ is irrelevant for my second example, I expect any value for $z$. If the maximization function is linear, this is what Mathematica does:

```
In : Maximize[{-x + y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y, z}]
Out: {1, {x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 0}}
```

In my third example, I expect a value for $z$ that satisfies the constraints. Again, a linear maximization function does achieve this:

```
In : Maximize[{-x + y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && x + 20 <= z}, {x, y, z}]
Out: {1, {x -> 0, y -> 1, z -> 20}}
```

If the constraints are unsatisfiable, Mathematica should realize this. Again, the behavior is as expected for linear functions:

```
In : Maximize[{-x + y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && z + 20 <= z}, {x, y,z}]
...  Maximize::infeas: There are no values of {x,y,z} for which the constraints 0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&20+z<=z are satisfied and the objective function -x+y is real-valued.
```

Comment: is $z$ a *variable* that is somehow affecting $x$ and $y$ or just a *parameter*? can you express $x$ and $y$ as $x=x(z)$ and $y=y(z)$?

Comment: No, x and y are independent of z (except in the third example, where x<=z because of the explicit constraint that enforces this).
My four examples require no setup, you can just run them. Examples 1 and 3 are returned unevaluated, while examples 2 and 4 are solved.

Comment: Try NMaximize?
`NMaximize[{-E^x + E^y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1}, {x, y, z}]`
This works for me if all you care about is getting max values for x and y

Comment: @MattStein: `NMaximize` maximizes numerically, but I want the precise maximum. For this example, `Maximize` should give me a maximum of $E-1$, while `NMaximize` returns $1.71828$.

Comment: What you are trying in third example is not possible. How is anyone supposed to know what to do with `z`? Knowing that `x<=z` does not tell anything about `z`. Can you try to describe your question differently?

Comment: What does that mean " I have additional variables that are irrelevant to the maximization problem." If z occurs in the equation, it is relevant, and if z occurs not there , you can use any z you want. Show us your exact optmization problem.

Comment: @ercegovac: I have added the expected behavior to my question. Hope that this clarifies your questions.

Comment: @Akku14: Maybe my edit answers your question. In general, it is not always syntactically obvious if a function depends on a variable or not. For example, `Maximize[-E^x + E^y + z - z, {x, y, z}]` does not actually depend on $z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a problem like this at work where I am matching multiple models to the same data, trying to see which set of models (and parameters) gives the tightest confidence... so I need exactly this kind of parameter dropping.

```
dropParsMaximize[{f_,cons_|PatternSequence[]},pars:_List|_,
 dom_|PatternSequence[],opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
 With[{p=Flatten@{pars}},With[{ps=Pick[p,!FreeQ[f,#]&/@p]},
 Maximize[{f,cons},ps,dom,opts]]]
dropParsMaximize[{-E^x+E^y,0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&x<=z},{x,y,z}]
(*drops z from parameters because it isn't in the objective*)
(*Maximize[{-E^x+E^y,0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&x<=z},{x,y}]*)    
dropConsParsMaximize[{f_,cons_},pars:_List|_,
 dom_|PatternSequence[],opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
 Maximize@@Block[{Maximize=dropConsParsMaximizeInternal},
  dropParsMaximize[{f,cons},pars,dom,opts]]
dropConsParsMaximizeInternal[{f_,cons_},pars_List,
 dom_|PatternSequence[],opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
 With[{cs=Pick[cons,Complement[Variables[#/.x_Symbol/;
  Context@x=!=Context[]:>List],pars]==={}&/@List@@cons]},
 {{f,cs},pars,dom,opts}]
dropConsParsMaximize[{-E^x+E^y,0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&x<=z},{x,y,z}]
(*drops z from parameters and then drops any constraints with z*)
(*{-1+E,{x->0,y->1}}*)
dropConsParsMaximizeCheckCons[{f_,cons_},pars:_List|_,
 dom_|PatternSequence[],opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
 With[{res=dropConsParsMaximize[{f,cons},pars,dom,opts]},Join[res,{cons}
  /.Last@res]]
dropConsParsMaximizeCheckCons[{-E^x+E^y,0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&z+20<=z},{x,y,z}]
(*as above, but constraints are substituted with solution*)
(*{-1+E,{x->0,y->1},20+z<=z}*)
```

Comment: FWIW, I personally find it fairly (and sometimes prohibitively) difficult to read code with a lot of horizontal scrolling, and I hope you'll consider instead splitting such code into multiple lines.  There are of course no hard and fast rules on this, and others might disagree with me, but I did find [this meta answer from a few years ago (see point 4)](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1028/11035) which mentions avoiding horizontal scrolling.  That said, thanks for your answers!  (and +1)